# typescript load() function constantly refreshing the page

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and a method I wrote in typescript causes the page to be constantly refreshed.
I want the language data to be pulled from the db and listed on the screen.
this is my html code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                    <img *ngIf="selectedLang != 'changeLanguage'" class="flag mr-2"
                         src="{{'/assets/media/flag/'+selectedLang+'.svg'}}" />
                    <b>{{selectedLang | translate}}</b>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <button (click)="onLanguageChange(lang)" class="dropdown-item btn-link pl-2"
                            *ngFor="let lang of translateService.getLangs()">
                        <img class="flag mr-2" src="{{'/assets/media/flag/'+lang+'.svg'}}" />
                        <b>{{lang | translate}}</b>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the code I wrote in the app.component.ts constructor method:

```
constructor(private translateService: TranslateService,
        private dashboardStoreService: DashboardStoreService,) {

        var list = [];

        new DataSource({
            store: this.dashboardStoreService.storeLanguage,
            select: [
                'code'
            ],
            filter: [['!', ['dataStatus', '=', DataStatus[DataStatus.Deleted]]]],

        }).load()
            .then((res) => {
                list = res.map(x => x.code);
                this.translateService.addLangs(list);
            });
    }`
```

The code in app.component.ts affects both the login screen and the pages after login. but it causes the login page to be constantly refreshed. Works fine on other pages how can i solve this problem?

Comment: There's not enough information here to tell but it looks like you have a number of race conditions.